# Sencha Touch + Cordova + Android - How to configure the project url?

Tags: android, ajax, .htaccess, cordova, sencha-touch-2

i am developing a project which have multiple sub domain. i used Sencha Touch framework and Cordova for android app. In browser project is working fine. i build android apk with signing apk for release mode.

i have a serious problem in server handling in ajax. whenever i try to reach server side using ajax, user session getting destroyed.

And i have doubt in my cordova config.xml settings too.

***My questions are :***

1. my project url like *.quiz.co . So **How to config my config.xml file and How do i specific that custom url for my project**. if i use window.open() or top.location.href or anything its redirect to my custom domain url but my android apk project works based on prodution codes not in apk codes.
2. when i launch my android apk in my mobile its beginning url is "**file:///assets/www.index.html**". So **How can i run my application based on custom domain like *.quiz.co**
3. When i using redirect to custom domain. Server side User Session getting destroy in each ajax call. So **How to maintain user session in ajax call ?**

config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<name>Master Quiz</name>

<description>
    Quiz Application for Android platform.
</description>

<icon src="www/img/icon.png" />
<icon src="www/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="xhdpi" />

<content src="index.html" />

<platform name="android">
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
</platform>

<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>

<!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix
to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
<allow-navigation href="*" />

<!-- Allow all unrecognized URLs to open installed apps
    *NOT RECOMMENDED* -->
<allow-intent href="*" />

<!-- Don't block any requests -->
<access origin="http://*" />

</widget>
```

Android Permissions :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Cordova? I ask because a recent release in April now mandates that you use the Cordova whitelist plugin.

Comment: Cordova version 4.1.2

Comment: Whitelisting was moved to a plugin [when 4.0 was released](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html).

Comment: Ya i check that document too. But i want to know  how android apk is working. I deployed codes in production So if i run mobile browser like http://adb.quiz.co  it will run. But in Android app If i gave url like that i will run based on production code. But that app didn't use apk code. Am i correct ?

Comment: I guess I dont understand what you're trying to do. Generally Cordova builds a native wrapper that loads a web view that loads the first page of your app. Your app presumably needs to make HTTP calls to send/receive data right? Without whitelisting you wont be able to make those calls at all. You can debug this easily enough by using the [remote debugging features in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). In the developer tools, look at the Network tab, it should show all calls and whether they succeeded or not.